# Piping unicode text into cmd.exe

Tags: windows, unicode, cmd, pipe, stdin

I wish to write unicode(UTF-16) text into cmd's stdin and read unicode from its stdout, yet cmd help only says it can output unicode with the /U switch. I notice there are QAs in this site claiming cmd.exe being capable of accepting unicode input, but can't find one that tells me how to do with pipes.

In the code sample below, a file with multilanguage name is created, then cmd.exe /U is used to manipulate it. The cmd process outputs utf-16 text correctly, but still expects ansi input.

```c
STARTUPINFOW si={.cb=sizeof(STARTUPINFOW),.dwFlags=STARTF_FORCEOFFFEEDBACK|STARTF_USESTDHANDLES};
HANDLE hWritePipeStdIn,hReadPipeStdOut;
CreatePipe(&si.hStdInput,&hWritePipeStdIn,0,0);
CreatePipe(&hReadPipeStdOut,&si.hStdOutput,0,0);
SetHandleInformation(si.hStdInput,HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT,1);
SetHandleInformation(si.hStdOutput,HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT,1);
si.hStdError=si.hStdOutput;



CloseHandle(CreateFileW(L".\\aaaالعربيةবাংলা日本語한국어ไทยTiếng ViệtYorùbá中文",FILE_WRITE_DATA,0,0,CREATE_ALWAYS,0,0));//create a file with multilanguage name
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
wchar_t cmdline[]=L"cmd.exe /U";//set output unicode
CreateProcessW(0,cmdline,0,0,1,CREATE_NO_WINDOW,0,0,&si,&pi);
CloseHandle(si.hStdInput);CloseHandle(si.hStdOutput);
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);CloseHandle(pi.hThread);


HANDLE hFile=CreateFileW(L".\\a.txt",FILE_WRITE_DATA,FILE_SHARE_READ,0,CREATE_ALWAYS,0,0);
char buf[512];DWORD len;
static char cmdline1[]="dir /b aaa*&exit\r\n";
WriteFile(hWritePipeStdIn,cmdline1,sizeof cmdline1-sizeof*cmdline1,&len,0);//still accepts ansi input
static wchar_t cmdline2[]=L"del aaaالعربيةবাংলা日本語한국어ไทยTiếng ViệtYorùbá中文&exit\r\n";
//WriteFile(hWritePipeStdIn,cmdline2,sizeof cmdline2-sizeof*cmdline2,&len,0);//can't use this. how to delete the file using cmd?
while(ReadFile(hReadPipeStdOut,buf,sizeof buf,&len,0))WriteFile(hFile,buf,len,&len,0);//a.txt is filled with legit UTF-16 text from the dir command
CloseHandle(hFile);
```

Comment: I don't think UTF-16 is supported for input. I've confirmed that CMD decodes input using the console's output codepage. So theoretically UTF-8 should be supported by attaching to the console via `AttachConsole(pi.dwProcessId)` and calling `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8)`. However, apparently CMD reads and decodes piped input one byte at a time, which is not compatible with multibyte UTF-8 (i.e. non-ASCII characters). When I tested with an `echo` statement, each byte of non-ASCII characters was decoded as the U+FFFD replacement character.

Comment: When you create a programming question, it is usual for you to include a tag for the programming language, for those who specialize in that language to actually see your question, and potentially assist you.

Comment: Question: why? What are you doing that requires `cmd` rather than using a normal programming/scripting language that has full native unicode support?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans
I use C code to show where the problem is in a more detailed way. But the real question is: how can existing command line programs and batch/scripts relying on them work with multilanguage file names if cmd does not support unicode input?

Comment: Batch scripts can use UTF-8 without a BOM. Restrict the script to ASCII except for string blocks that define environment variables for Unicode usernames and file/registry paths. A string block can temporarily change the console session's output codepage (which CMD uses when decoding input from files and pipes) to UTF-8 via `chcp.com 65001`. This works because CMD decodes files line by line and checks the console's output codepage for each line. It won't work if CMD is run without a console session (i.e. `DETACHED_PROCESS`), in which case CMD defaults to the process active (ANSI) codepage.